# how to determine number of employees absent for the current day using mysql

Tags: mysql

infact my project is centered on empolyee attendance system.
so for that i need to calculate the number of employees absent for the current day "AND NOT THE PREVIOUS DAYS" given the following two tables

1=users( 
        id PK
    name
    surname
    username)

2=time(
         id PK
    time_in   type=time
    date_in   type=date
    time_out    type=time
    date_out    type=date
    id_users FK)

Comment: Fundamental understanding of MySQL would greatly benefit you. This site is for helping people who have already done their homework, not doing it for them. You should start with a MySQL tutorial. I would provide you a link but if you are here then you know how to Google something.

Comment: Thanks for advice . Now lets analyse your code together if we apply your code it will always   show that a user is absent given that the date which you are selecting are the previous dates.

Comment: HINT: We should select  an employee's LAST date_in and test if it is different from the current date.  this last date which represent the last time when an employee was present ,if it is different from the current date , then the it implies the employee is absent for the current day.

Comment: NOW the problem i have is to impliment my idea...Thats where i am asking for your help concerning the right code

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
    u.id, u.name 
From 
    users u 
Inner Join 
    time t On u.id = t.id_users 
Where t.date_in <> CURDATE()
```

Comment: Please avoid posting code-only answers. Add some description as to why this code solves the problem shown in the question.